# Django FormWizard as_view() method AttributeError

Tags: django, forms, session, wizard

I want to incorporate a FormWizard to handle a long form. After researching, it seems that [django-merlin](https://github.com/supercodepoet/django-merlin) is the best option since it manages the formwizard via sessions. Trying to incorporate it (as mentioned in the [django wizard docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)), however, results in an `AttributeError: type object 'CreateWizard' has no attribute 'as_view'`.

Here is what it looks like:

```
from merlin.wizards.session import SessionWizard

class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
    ...

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.ImageField()
    ...

class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONDITION)
    ...

class CreateWizard(SessionWizard):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wizard-done'))
```

url:

```
url(r'^wizard/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$', CreateWizard.as_view([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm])),
```

Since the merlin docs are a little sparse, I chose to use the `as_view()` method as described in the original django form wizard docs, but it results in an `AttributeError`. How should I incorporate the merlin wizard in my urlconf?  Thanks for your ideas!

---

This is the error and traceback that I get after updating based on @mVChr's answer and defining steps like this:

```
step_one = Step('step_one', StepOneForm())
```

Error and Traceback:

```
TypeError at / issubclass() arg 1 must be a class

Traceback:
File /lib/python2.7/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/lib/python2.7/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/myproject/myproject/urls.py" in <module>
  7. from myapp.forms import step_one, step_two, step_three, CreateWizard
File "/myproject/myapp/forms.py" in <module>
  16. step_one = Step('step_one', StepOneForm())
File "/lib/python2.7/merlin/wizards/utils.py" in __init__
  36.         if not issubclass(form, (forms.Form, forms.ModelForm,)):

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class
```

Although Im still getting an error, I feel closer to the solution thanks to @mVChr. Any ideas on how to solve this error are greatly appreciated! Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried just `CreateWizard([StepOneForm, StepTwoForm, StepThreeForm])` ([see docs](http://packages.python.org/django-merlin/sessionwizard.html#how-to-use-sessionwizard))?  Also, it seems you need to pass [`Step` objects](http://packages.python.org/django-merlin/api/step.html#api-step) and not django `Form` objects.

Comment: That gives me another error: `TypeError at / All steps must be an instance of Step`. This is [located here](https://github.com/supercodepoet/django-merlin/blob/master/src/merlin/wizards/session.py) in the merlin source, line 42. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: @mVChr: Thanks for your ideas. Could you provide a small example to illustrate how to pass Step objects instead of the forms? That would really help me understand how to solve this issue

Comment: @NickB: do you have working code using django-merlin. I want to use this, but documentation is poor with no examples. if you have some working code to show, that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Note: I do not know if this will work, I am just trying to help Nick B translate the docs with a specific example to get him closer to the proper solution.  Please let me know if this works as-is and I will remove this comment.

From reading [the docs](http://packages.python.org/django-merlin/) it looks like you need to pass a list of `Step` objects directly to your `SessionWizard` subclass instantiation, as follows:

```
from merlin.wizards.session import SessionWizard
from merlin.wizards.utils import Step

class StepOneForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
    ...
step_one = Step('step-one', StepOneForm())

class StepTwoForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.ImageField()
    ...
step_two = Step('step-two', StepTwoForm())

class StepThreeForm(forms.Form):
    condition = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CONDITION)
    ...
step_three = Step('step-three', StepThreeForm())

class CreateWizard(SessionWizard):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('wizard-done'))
```

And then in your `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^wizard/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$',
    CreateWizard([step_one, step_two, step_three]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas @mVChr! Followed your advice and I think I am a lot closer, but I have a new error message now: `TypeError at /issubclass() arg 1 must be a class.` Also, `Form must be a subclass of a Django Form`. Looking at the local variables in the debug screen also tells me: `self: Error in formatting: 'Step' object has no attribute 'slug'`. I'm not sure how to proceed to solve this error, but would greatly appreciate any tidbits of wisdom! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Want to draw your attention that you use wrong syntax while making an object of Step.
This

```
step_one = Step('step-one', StepOneForm())
```

should be like

```
step_one = Step('step-one', StepOneForm)
```

You have to correct it in all step object.